# Flashing a hex file into AVR microcontroller

Tags: c, qt-creator, avr, avrdude

I am using a QT creator to program for AVR (ATMEGA328P) to be specific. I have linked to the toolchain and included the libraries. I have specified my programmer as arduino in the .pro file. However, avrdude displays an error that programmer is not specified. I have tried flashing the hex code via my ubuntu terminal and it is working fine, however I cannot do the same via QT creator.
Kindly help me out.

Below are the details in my .pro file

***programmer as -c arduino
baudrate as 115200
processor as ATMEGA328P
port as /dev/ttyACM0***

This is the error that I get:

The image of the error that i get

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/eng-mg/CuteAVR

Comment: Are you sure your chip does in fact have the Arduino bootloader installed on it? What's your actual avrdude command line?

Comment: Maybe have a look here : https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/5427